# Cast returned value into x digit long integer

Tags: sql, int, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to return a value as a 7 digit integer? I'm only finding it possible to just return as an integer with no other options.

Comment: Are you looking for how to pad with 0s if the number is less than seven digits long?

Comment: Basically, yes. But I need to use the CAST function

Comment: Is `CAST` a requirement for your project? Looking around, it seems like `SELECT LPAD(numCol, 7, '0') FROM yourTable` should work regardless of if `numCol` is a number or string.

Comment: It is, which I don't understand why. I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this will be very similar syntax in Oracle.  In SQL server the syntax would be:

`SELECT RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(MyInt as varchar(7)), 7)`

This will return a 0-padded string representing your number.  Bear in mind this will have to be a STRING not an actual numerical value if you want 0-padding.

Comment: Hm. Doesn't seem to like the 'RIGHT' function

Comment: Apparently the equivalent in oracle is `SUBSTR(XXXX, -7)`

Comment: I tried `SUBSTR('0000000' + CAST(invoice_total as varchar(7)), -7)` but that just returns a decimal with 7 digits

Comment: @afdave14 Sorry in Oracle you need to concatenate with `||` so `SUBSTR('0000000' || CAST(invoice_total as varchar(7)), -7)`